# How to include multiple models in openerp report section

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I have created a new module in openerp.Now want to create report .I have done everything for reporting.My module concept is  User can create a consumption chart, it contain chart name ,date and project name .Each chart contain muliple products and their consumpion quantity.Consumption Chart details are in one table and product details related to a consumption chart in another table. I want to show a report with consumption chart name and its product details.I have prepared a report , so when take the pdf I can see the consumption chart details how can I include the product details. My question is how to include multiple models in the report section.Below given is my current code.

```
class order(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(order, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
        })


report_sxw.report_sxw('report.mat_mgmt.collection_docket', 'mat.mgmt', 'mat_magmt/report/collection_docket.rml', parser=order, header="external")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object for any model like `self.pool.get('product.product')` and then you can browse its record. If you have any **relation with model/object** you can directly access them. There are lots of examples in addons.

Comment: can you specify any example addon

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in the parser to return product details:

```
class order(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(order, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'details': _get_details,
        })

    def _get_details(self, product_id):
        product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(self.cr, self.uid, product_id)

        # get product details

        return product_details


report_sxw.report_sxw('report.mat_mgmt.collection_docket', 'mat.mgmt', 'mat_magmt/report/collection_docket.rml', parser=order, header="external")
```